# Inequality on Mahalanobis distance

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, positive-semidefinite

If $x^Tx \geq y^Ty$, what are the conditions on $R$ to be $x^TRx \geq y^TRy$ for a positive semidefinite $R$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider an example where $\textbf{x}= [2 \quad 0]^{\top}, \textbf{y}= [0 \quad 1]^{\top}$ and $\mathbf{R}= \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 6}$. In that case, $\lVert \textbf{x} \rVert^2 = 4$ and $\lVert \textbf{y} \rVert^2 = 1$, but $\textbf{x}^{\top} \mathbf{R} \textbf{x} = 4$ and $\textbf{y}^{\top} \mathbf{R} \textbf{y} = 6$.

So, even if $\mathbf{R}$ is PD that does not guarantee your desired inequality.

---

From the example, we can conclude that the scaling must be uniform in all directions, that is, eigenvalues must be the same.

Let us consider that $\mathbf{R}$ is a symmetric matrix. We can write as follows:
$$\mathbf{R}=\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{Q}^{\top}=\lambda\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{I}\mathbf{Q}^{\top}=\lambda\mathbf{I}.$$
Now,
$$\textbf{x}^{\top}\mathbf{R}\textbf{x}=\lambda \lVert \textbf{x} \rVert^2.$$
In order to maintain the inequality, we need $\lambda > 0$.

[Note: The above analysis is valid only when $\mathbf{R}$ is symmetric.]

Comment: Thanks Rajat. I see PD condition itself is not enough. Can we find out what are the other conditions on $R$ for the second inequality to be true ?

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Looking at eigenvalues seems to be helpful. This can be regarded as a special case where all the eigenvalues are equal.